# Sql update a column value with condition for different column values

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, join

I have  a sql table with below columns .I want to update the finalRole column based on value from other Superadminrole column  .If there is superadminrole, finalrole column should be updated with superadminrole value else with grouprole column value

```
Groupid   OwnerGid  SuperAdminGroupId   groupRole   ownerRole  SuperAdminRole  FInalRole
-----   ----------   ----------------   ---------   ---------  --------------  ---------
17     20             3                  Admin       User       SAdmin      Sadmin

2       null          null               Admin                               Admin
```

Comment: Where is it you are stuck exactly? At working out how to return a different value when the first is `NULL` in SQL? How to write the `UPDATE` statement? How to run the `UPDATE` statement using asp.net? Something else? [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983) What have you tried? Why isn't it working?

Comment: I tried by wrting case statement but its not working

Comment: Are you looking this? 
`UPDATE TableName SET FInalRole = CASE WHEN ISNULL(SuperAdminRole, '') = '' THEN groupRole WHEN ISNULL(SuperAdminRole, '') != '' THEN SuperAdminRole ELSE '' END
`

or can use IIF as `SET FinalRole = IIF(ISNULL(SuperAdminRole, '') != '', SuperAdminRole, groupRole)`

Comment: In what? ASP.Net? What language is your application in? C#? T-SQL doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) statements, only `CASE` expressions.

Comment: I am trying in Sql server

Comment: Again, see my original comment. [Edit] your question  to explicitly show where you are stuck. demonstrate your attempts. *Explain* why they aren't working,.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) expression should be as below:

```
UPDATE TableName SET 
       FinalRole = CASE WHEN ISNULL(SuperAdminRole, '') = '' THEN groupRole 
                        WHEN ISNULL(SuperAdminRole, '') != '' THEN SuperAdminRole 
                        ELSE '' END
```

or you may use [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) logical expression:

```
UPDATE TableName SET 
       FinalRole = IIF(ISNULL(SuperAdminRole, '') != '', SuperAdminRole, groupRole)
```